# define two execution regions on arm9

Tags: arm, scatter, keil, linkage

I am using ARM 9, all code stored on flash.
Flash contains booter (boot loader) and two load regions.

How can I build my binary so I can use **same** binary and be able to store it in load region 1 or load region 2?

Using the scatter file I configured load regions and execution regions.
The output binary works ok if I load the binary to from load region 1.

However if binary is placed in flash to into load region 2, I face a problem.
This is because the binary contains the outcome of the scatter file, with absolute address matching the load region 1. So when scatter loading begins, arm will access address from region 1 instead of loading from region 2.

I read about PI (position independence) option but don't know how it helps.

PS. My application support sw upgrade, i can load from region 1, 
but if i need to upgrade, then i download new binary to load region 2 and load from image 2. next upgrade i will download the new image into region 1, and load from image 1, etc..

flash has next load regions:
LR0: not important.
LR1: 0x8100000, size: yyy (this is load region 1).
LR2: 0x8200000, size: yyy (this is load region 2).

By default i load from LR1 (this is the application).
For SW upgrade i download the image to LR2.
Now i want this image to load from LR2.
I image is linked to load from LR2 - then no problem (since addressed match this region).
However i dont know ahead if image will be stored in LR1 or LR2, and hence the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not an answer but a workaround: When I encountered this situation I ended up linking the application twice, with different scripts, extracting the binaries with objcopy, and chopping up the binary files together to get both (different) images for each version of the code. I would be interested to read the answers how to do it "properly" with PIC.

Comment: Hi Nick, my goal is to avoid creating different image.
the reason is because i want to generate a generic image (without knowing ahead if it will be stored in region 1 or 2 on flash), then during upgrade my application will decide at which region to store the  new binary. so basically i don't know how make my scatter setting be dynamic

Comment: Sorry; Running the linker twice and generating a matching pair of images solved my problem. I kept the images together to decide at run-time which one to load. (I also considered using the upper slot as a buffer and copying everything to the lower slot: this requires a much more complicated bootloader with more error checking and twice as much flash write traffic.) I don't have a better answer. I'd be interested to read if there is a more elegant way to do it...